# spring-security returns 401 despite authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-oauth2

I'm using `spring-security` and `spring-security-oauth2` (JWT access tokens) for authentication and authorization. The idea is to let all requests through, but to be able to distinguish between authenticated users and unauthenticated users. As soon as I enable `@EnableResourceServer` my configured `HttpSecurity` seems to get ignored. And requests return 401:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Here's the config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan
@EnableWebSecurity
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF).run(args);
    }

    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter) {
            final DefaultAccessTokenConverter conv = new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
            conv.setUserTokenConverter(userAuthenticationConverter());
            converter.setAccessTokenConverter(conv);

        }

        @Bean
        public UserAuthenticationConverter userAuthenticationConverter() {
            return new ResourceAuthenticationConverter();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. It's an easy fix - the [javadoc of @EnableResourceServer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableResourceServer.html) provides the answer:

> Users should add this annotation and provide a @Bean of type
>   ResourceServerConfigurer (e.g. via ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter)
>   that specifies the details of the resource (URL paths and resource
>   id).

You're using a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` however. Just change it to `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` and enhance the visibility of `configure`:

```
@EnableResourceServer
public static class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter implements JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer {
// snip
        @Override
        public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
// snip
```